# Bootstrap collapsible behaves weird

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

My problem is sampled in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qtgye/8hyepbyk/1/)  .

I have a basic collapsible element with a toggle button inside:

```
<div class="visible-xs collapsible collapse in panel panel-primary">
    <div>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Hic veritatis fugit veniam sapiente rem excepturi velit animi inventore mollitia reprehenderit nostrum natus autem quae minima dolor dolores voluptatum eum quia.
    </div>
    <br />
    <div class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".collapsible">Collapse</div>
</div>
```

When the element collapses, the children elements jumps out of the collapsible.

What's wrong here?

Comment: your collapse should be the inner div instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of the `visible-xs` class.

```
<div class="collapsible collapse in panel panel-primary">
```

http://jsfiddle.net/g238b1qn/